# Return value on virtual methods

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

I inherited an application that was building perfectly on clang and GCC. Now, I'm trying to port it on Windows. When I tried to built it with visual studio 2010 I got the error that I try to contextualize with the following example.

Consider the `Interface` class:

```
class Interface
{
public:

    virtual ~Interface(){}

    virtual void someMethod() = 0;
    virtual QVector<int >& getSomething(){}
};
```

Where `someMethod` is pure virtual and `getSomething` is virtual.

Then two derived classes `Derived`

```
class Derived : public Interface
{
public:
    Derived(){ cout << "derived constructor";}

    ~Derived(){ cout << "derived destructor";}

    virtual void someMethod() override { cout << "derived someMethod";}

};
```

Which implements just the pure virtual method, and  `DerivedB`:

```
class DerivedB : public Interface
{
public:
    DerivedB(){ cout << "derivedB constructor";}
    ~DerivedB(){ cout << "derivedB destructor";}
    virtual void someMethod() override { cout << "derivedB someMethod";}
    virtual QVector<int >& getSomething(){ return myComputedVector; }
};
```

Which implements both the pure virtual and the virtual method.

Summarizing, I have some classes that implement `getSomething()` and all classes implementing `someMethod()`.

If I try to build this code with visual studio I get the following error:

```
error C4716: 'Interface::getSomething' : must return a value
```

I understand the compiler, but I don't know how to manage this situation.
If some one can explain me or give me a simple example on how to manage this, I'd be really helpful!!

Comment: The default implementation for `getSomething` is not valid c++. Shouldn't it also be pure virtual? What is the intention behind giving `getSomething` an empty body?

Comment: A function declared to return something, and that is implemented, *must* return something. It has nothing to do with inheritance or `virtual`, it's just that something must be returned from the function.

Comment: Either make Interface::getSomething() pure virtual, or have it return something.

Comment: I've voted to close this as being caused by a simple typographic error. If you don't have an implementation in the current class, don't define one.

Comment: @paperox do you want _some_ classes that implement `getSomething()` and _all_ classes implementing `someMethod()`? To do so you'd need to break your original interface and derive from both when needed (multiple inheritance is allowed in C++).

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but I don't know how to do it in practically. How to manage the situation when just some classes implement `someMethod`?

Comment: @paperox Sergey asked if you need _all_ classes to implement `someMethod()`, and you said that is exactly what you need, but then said you need only _some_ classes to implement `someMethod()`. Which is it? Anyway, if you only need some classes to implement a method, two answers were already given: (A) declare the method pure virtual in the base and only implement where needed, or (B) create a new base class introducing the method and only inherit from that in classes that need to implement it. Which to choose depends on whether you need to instantiate classes that don't implement it.

Comment: @underscore_d I need all classes to implement `someMethod()`, but only some implementing `getSomething()`, which returns some reference. I can't declare the `getSomething()` method pure virtual in the base class, otherwise I'm forced to define its implementation in all derived..

Answer (score 8):

The function

`virtual QVector<int >& getSomething(){}`

needs to return a reference to a `QVector<int>`. The empty function body that you have supplied by way of an *implementation* of this function is not doing that. Your helpful compiler is informing you of that.